# Can't open Crystal Report Designer in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How do I change the file associations for .RPT?  Because I cannot open Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008. When I attempt to open it, it appears to be binary. I've done a re-install of Crystal Reports and Visual Studio 2008, but was still not able to open the RPT file. There seems to be a problem in the default program used to open a file. RPT, how do I restore the default?

Comment: You did not reinstall VS after CR did you? Because then all addins will have been removed...
But you might be able to open it, right click the file, say "open with..." and then manually select crystal reports. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new crystal reports project then you should be able to add the existing report to the project and open it.